# PowerBI Desktop Custom Visual - Storage Problem

Tags: powerbi-custom-visuals

i developed an custom filter for iso calender weeks for my company in PowerBI.

It works very well, but i am not able to save the current filter to the localstorage. It works on the web when its published but not in the desktop version.

```
import ILocalVisualStorageService = powerbi.extensibility.ILocalVisualStorageService;



constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions){
    this.storage = options.host.storageService;
}
```

in my first update cycle i check for the localstorage and set if necessary.

```
//to get data in async function
let cache = await this.storage.get("filter");


//to set data in async function
await this.storage.set("filter", "xyz");
```

Is it possible to use the localstorage  in Desktop?

Kind Regards

Tobias

Answer (score 1):

Did you try contacting Power BI visuals support to activate the local storage API, as it is not activated by default?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/local-storage

Alternatively, for your use case it might be better to use the **persistProperties** service. There is very little documentation about this feature on the PBI Visuals documentation website, but you can find an example in powerbi-visuals-sankey custom visual, where it is used to store various properties.

https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-sankey

A rough example for your case:

```
options.host.persistProperties({
            VisualObjectInstance = {
            objectName: "filterSetting",
            selector: undefined, 
            properties: {
                filter: "xyz"
            }
        };
     });
```

After triggering the persistProperties function, the visual triggers an update, populating the VisualUpdateOptions' options.dataViews.metadata.objects with the persisted property. Note, that you have to define your property in the capabilities.json beforehand.